# Create bean with factory-method with java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I have an aspect which creates by load-time weaving mechanism. But I need to inject my service in it, so it aspect must be created by spring. 
My aspect looks like this :

```
@Aspect
public class SomeAspect {

  @Inject
  private SomeService someService;

  @Before("some_pointcut_here")
  public void doInterception() {
    //...call service here
  }

}
```

I can do it with xml:

```
<bean id="myAspect" class="foo.bar.SomeAspect" factory-method="aspectOf" />
```

So the question is how to achieve the same with spring java config. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks

**Edit**

I annotate my aspect with @Component and it works. It strange for me because in case of xml config dependency injection doesn't worked in my case, but it works for java configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Bean
public SomeAspect someAspect() {
    return org.aspectj.lang.Aspects.aspectOf(SomeAspect.class);
}
```

Comment: SomeAspect hasn't got method aspectOf at compile time. This method will be added by aspectJ weaver.

Comment: I have tried this one, but NoSuchMethodException was occurred. Then I try to annotate my aspect with @Component and it works. It strange for me because when i do the same with xml config,  dependency injection isn't worked. But it works for java config. Thanks for your help and sorry for wasting your time

Comment: @AnatoliiVakaliuk, if answer helped you do not forget to upvote and mark it as correct answer.